# Logging in to Windows 7 with one specific user account is very slow. Why?

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) and I have created 3 user accounts, two regular users and one administrator.

When logging in as the administrator or as one of the user accounts I get to a usable desktop in about 2-3 seconds.

The other user account consistently takes about 10 seconds to login. I have deleted it and recreated it twice, using a different user name the second time and yet it is still 3-4 times slower to login that the other accounts.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be or how to fix it? Is there some special registry magic required to finally kill off a user that the control panel delete doesn't do?

Is it a coincidence that the slow account is always the first in the list of accounts at bootup? (first on the left)?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

- Delete the affected user account in the control panel
- Delete the user profile and user directory manually

  - Delete the `c:\users\username\` directory completely
- Restart the computer
- Create the account
- Log in to this account for the first time
- Restart the computer
- Log in to this account for the second time

The second log in time for this newly created account should be as quick as the other users'.

Comment: I can't up vote this unfortunately, as I don't have the rep. Which is a shame as it's a good answer.

Comment: upvoted for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is so strange I can't belive it.

In the user account with the slower login I had 'personalized' the desktop to remove the wallpaper and have a solid black desltop.

When I undid this personalization and went back to one of the default themes with a wallpaper set, login time zipped back up to 2-3 seconds.

The other user accounts have one of the standard themes with backgrounds set as well.

So a solid colour desktop instead of wallpaper appears to slow login time by 10 seconds. Set a wallpaper and it logs in fast again. It works for me, but can anyone else confirm that?

Comment: You could verify it by changing to a solid colour desktop on the other user account.

Answer (score 0):

@chimpboy,

yeah, so true, having a solid color desktop wallpaper would slow down the log in in windows 7, i used to have a black solid color wallpaper back in xp and vista and i tried it in win7, strange may it seem but so true, it slows down the log in time, so i just settled in to a personalized doggie wallpaper, and the log in time is so much faster...

im using 32 bit only. ultimate win7.
and same experience as yours..

--decoder